# Why my gatsby build failed on Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory?

Tags: javascript, webpack, caching, gatsby

I'm generating a gatsby site working fine with gatsby development but while creating it's build that's throwing an error

```
success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 26.183s
⠇ Building Rendering Engines
[ ] 45.509 42/47 9 Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING … s 7 %
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (11572kiB)
impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (11572kiB)
impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
⠙ Building Rendering Engines
[ ] 64.883 44/47 9 Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING … s 7 %
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (127kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (127kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
success Building Rendering Engines - 69.787s
success Building HTML renderer - 70.287s
success Execute page configs - 0.050s
failed Validating Rendering Engines - 73.109s

ERROR #98001 WEBPACK

Built Rendering Engines failed validation failed validation.

Please open an issue with a reproduction at
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/new for more help



Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\UCHE\Desktop\own-r eview\site\.cache\query-engine\interfaces.gql'

- node:fs:585 Object.openSync
node:fs:585:3

- node:fs:453 Object.readFileSync
node:fs:453:35
- index.js:708656 Object.<anonymous>
C:/Users/UCHE/Desktop/own-review/site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:708656 :17

- index.js:734538 __webpack_require__
C:/Users/UCHE/Desktop/own-review/site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:734538 :42

- index.js:708375 Object.<anonymous>
C:/Users/UCHE/Desktop/own-review/site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:708375 :19

- index.js:734538 __webpack_require__
C:/Users/UCHE/Desktop/own-review/site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:734538 :42

- index.js:708334 Object.<anonymous>
C:/Users/UCHE/Desktop/own-review/site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:708334 :22

- index.js:734538 __webpack_require__
C:/Users/UCHE/Desktop/own-review/site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:734538 :42

- index.js:708328 Object.<anonymous>
C:/Users/UCHE/Desktop/own-review/site/.cache/query-engine/index.js:708328 :37

- index.js:734538 __webpack_require__
C:/Users/UCHE/Desktop/own-review/site/.cache/query-engine/index.
```

I tried to rebuild after running gatsby clean, delete the.cache file, reinstalled the node_module but no luck yet

Anybody known how can I solve this error?

Comment: Have you tried using a path without whitespace? `own-r eview` this part may conflict

Comment: Sorry?
Where to do these changes?

Comment: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\UCHE\Desktop\own-r eview\site\.cache\query-engine\interfaces.gql'` The path of your project... Have you tried changing it?

Comment: The path was correct

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the `.cache` directory in your gatsby project and run `yarn start` or `yarn build` again (or the equivalent `npm` commands if you are using `npm`), this resolved all of the `webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy` related issues for me...